# Access error 3464 with DCount function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table Part_Information in which PartNumber is a text field. On a form when user enters PartNumber in textbox I need to check whether that partNumber exists in table or not.  I am using `Dcount` method.

```
DCount(" PartNumber ", "Part_Information", "PartNumber = " & Me.CurrentPartNumber) = 0
```

but it gives error 3464 saying data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Answer (score 2):

If PartNumber is a text field, you have to quote the criteria like this:

```
DCount("PartNumber","Part_Information","PartNumber='" & Me.CurrentPartNumber & "'")
```